# Error ploting bode , nyquist and nichols responses in gui matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to create a graphical interface with the GUIDE Matlab that displays diffrent responses of a transfer function  : step , impulse , bode , nyquist and nichols responses.
it works fine for the step and impulse responses but with nyquist , bode and nichols it dosen't work , i should add 'squeeze' to the 'plot' function but it's not exactly the correct response !
this is the error when i try with plot only :

**??? Error using ==> plot Data may not have more than 2 dimensions**
This is th [LTI](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kyzxf2bn2f4p5n/LTI.fig?dl=0).fig file
The following code is the content of the .m file

```
function varargout = LTI(varargin)
% LTI M-file for LTI.fig
%      LTI, by itself, creates a new LTI or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = LTI returns the handle to a new LTI or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      LTI('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in LTI.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      LTI('Property','Value',...) creates a new LTI or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before LTI_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to LTI_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help LTI

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 24-Nov-2014 10:41:38

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
               'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
               'gui_OpeningFcn', @LTI_OpeningFcn, ...
               'gui_OutputFcn',  @LTI_OutputFcn, ...
               'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
               'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
   [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before LTI is made visible.
function LTI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to LTI (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for LTI
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes LTI wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = LTI_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;



function numerateur_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to numerateur (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of numerateur as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of numerateur as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function numerateur_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to numerateur (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function denumerateur_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to denumerateur (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of denumerateur as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of denumerateur as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function denumerateur_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to denumerateur (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end


% --- Executes on button press in rep_indic.
function rep_indic_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to rep_indic (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
num= str2num(get(handles.numerateur,'String'));
denum = str2num(get(handles.denumerateur,'String'));
G=tf([num],[denum]);
axes(handles.figure)
plot(step(G))
grid on


% --- Executes on button press in lieu_bode.
function lieu_bode_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to lieu_bode (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
num= str2num(get(handles.numerateur,'String'));
denum = str2num(get(handles.denumerateur,'String'));
G=tf([num],[denum]);
axes(handles.figure)
plot(squeeze(bode(G)))
grid on

% --- Executes on button press in rep_impuls.
function rep_impuls_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to rep_impuls (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
num= str2num(get(handles.numerateur,'String'));
denum = str2num(get(handles.denumerateur,'String'));
G=tf([num],[denum]);
axes(handles.figure)
plot(impulse(G))
grid on

% --- Executes on button press in lieu_nyquist.
function lieu_nyquist_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to lieu_nyquist (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
num= str2num(get(handles.numerateur,'String'));
denum = str2num(get(handles.denumerateur,'String'));
G=tf([num],[denum]);
axes(handles.figure)
plot(s(nyquist(G)))
grid on

% --- Executes on button press in lieu_nichols.
function lieu_nichols_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to lieu_nichols (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
num= str2num(get(handles.numerateur,'String'));
denum = str2num(get(handles.denumerateur,'String'));
G=tf([num],[denum]);
axes(handles.figure)
plot(squeeze(nichols(G)))
grid on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide the *.fig file to go with your code, but I suspect I know what the problem is: [`bode`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/bode.html), [`nyquist`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/nyquist.html) and [`nichols`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/nichols.html) produce the plot automatically, you don't need to call the `plot` function. Check the documentation for the correct way to call these functions. In your GUI, replace:

1. `plot(squeeze(bode(G)))` by `bode(G)`
2. `plot(s(nyquist(G)))` [sic] by `nyquist(G)`
3. `plot(squeeze(nichols(G)))` by `nichols(G)`

**EDIT based on comments**

I think all you need to do is

```
num= str2num(get(handles.numerateur,'String'));
denum = str2num(get(handles.denumerateur,'String'));
G=tf([num],[denum]);
axes(handles.figure)
step(G)
grid on
```

and the same applies for `bode`, `nyquist`, `nichols` and `impulse`, i.e. just create a set of axes in the figure and the plot will be displayed in those axes by default.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i know that they produce the plot automatically , but that dosen't work for me. It only worked in the 'workspace' ! 
How could i add the *.fig file ? i'm new to this forum so i will be greatful if you can be patient with me

Comment: Can you provide `LTI.fig` so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: when i tried this
    handles.axes = axes(handles.figure);
    bode(handles.axes,G)
it showed me this error :

**??? Error using ==> axes
Too many output arguments.

Error in ==> LTI>lieu_bode_Callback at 143
handles.axes=axes(handles.figure)

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
   feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> LTI at 42
   gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback**

i don't know how to add the LTI.fig to the subject ! how can i do it

Comment: I corrected the edit in my answer. Just upload the fig file to some free filesharing site and provide a link to it in your question.

Comment: thank you for you patience ! i just edited the subject and uploaded the .fig file  
You can find it before the content of the .m file  
Thank you again

Comment: Thank you again but it didn't work , i got an idea ! how can i display the response in an other figure ! maybe that will work

Comment: What didn't work? It should work. Which release are you using?

Comment: i'm using matlab 7.5.0(R2007b)

Comment: I can only access the documentation online for the latest release (R2014b), so it's quite possible something has changed in the last 7 years. The code should work just fine for R2014b. You haven't said "what doesn't work".

Comment: I changed the version from 7.5.0(R2007b) to 7.11.0(R2010b) ! the code worked fine for me :D , Thank you alot :)